# how to read string which is written outside the html <> tags.?

Tags: java, html, string, file-io, substring

I am having **HTML** code of 1000 lines and I wanted to extract the data which is written outside the HTML <> Tags.

for example..

```
<>Java Programm<>
```

It should read only "Java Programm" and escape whatever written inside the "<>" tags

I tried following code but it is reading whole data including <> but I do not need "<>" in my output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\File.txt");
        int i;
        while ((i=fin.read())!=-1) {
            System.out.print((char)i);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, you're reading text file. What did you try to actually solve your specific problem (ignoring tags)?

Comment: @Adriano : The OP haven't try anything, he just posted the question. Just copy the file read code and further for us..

Comment: Hint: Read it as XML (google read xml in java). use element.getTextContent to get the data outside the tags...

Comment: @Hirak I didn't get..

Answer (score 0):

You would need an HTML parser. For JSoup it's

```
File input = new File("C:\\Users\\File.txt");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");   
Element body = doc.body(); //Get the body of the html
System.out.println(body.text()) ; //Get the all the text inside the body tag
```

This is one way to do it. Simple enough :), there of course are other ways to do it. This ofcourse will leave the text outside of body tag. You can explore JSoup [a here](http://jsoup.org/) and find a solution for it.